# Github Actions remote repo issues

Tags: github, github-actions

I am using Github and I need to implement a feature using Github Actions as per below:

I have two repos - one private and one public.
Whenever a pull request is created for 'master' branch on the public reposity we need to push the source branch (altogether) into the private repository.

My workflow file looks like below:

```
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      # Runs a set of commands using the runners shell
      - name: Run a multi-line script
        env:
         INTERVIEW_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.INTERVIEW_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          echo ${{github.head_ref}}
          git remote -v 
          git fetch
          git checkout ${{github.head_ref}}
          git remote add private-origin https://stoicad:$INTERVIEW_TOKEN@github.com/stoicad/interview-private.git
          git remote -v 
          git push -u private-origin ${{github.head_ref}}
```

It should be pretty straightforward:

- fetch from origin
- checkout PR 'source' branch
- set a new remote (called private-origin) - the generated token has all permission!
- check to see if the new remote was set
- push changes to private-repo

The actual result:

```
PR_TEST_BRANCH
origin  https://github.com/stoicad/interview (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/stoicad/interview (push)
From https://github.com/stoicad/interview
 * [new branch]      PR_TEST_BRANCH -> origin/PR_TEST_BRANCH
 * [new branch]      master         -> origin/master
Previous HEAD position was 7607d53 Merge e1fa33b54d0611dd0b5c5ccfe86d9d00442cdcbb into f882b0a96f557dfe1614fb79920799167b1963a7
Switched to a new branch 'PR_TEST_BRANCH'
Branch 'PR_TEST_BRANCH' set up to track remote branch 'PR_TEST_BRANCH' from 'origin'.
origin  https://github.com/stoicad/interview (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/stoicad/interview (push)
private-origin  ***github.com/stoicad/interview-private.git (fetch)
private-origin  ***github.com/stoicad/interview-private.git (push)
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/stoicad/interview-private.git/' not found
Error: Process completed with exit code 128.
```

Am I missing something? Both repositories were created by myself, the generated token has for sure all the rights, what else can be? Why it throws an error saying "Repository not found"?

Comment: Just as a general rule—the specifics are *all* up to GitHub; Git plays no role in any of this here—Git *Hub* will lie about the existence, or non-existence, of a repository in order to keep private repositories private. So it seems likely that GitHub doesn't think your generated token gives access rights. Why *that* might be, I have no idea, but the github and github-actions tags are the right tags here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ended up with the following solution based on Sam-Sundar answer:

1. Generate ssh key using: `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -a 100` (when you're asked for a passphrase just hit enter)
2. Register **public** key on Github **private** repository (interview.git) under

> Settings > Deploy Keys > Add Deploy Key

3. Store **private** key on Github **public** repository (interview-private.git) under

> Settings > Secrets > New Repository Secret (*I called it INTERVIEW_TOKEN*)

4. Update workflow file with:

   [image]

Sorry for posting an image, but the code formatting from stackoverflow it's not working with those git commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this [action](https://github.com/webfactory/ssh-agent) after your checkout step and then you can push to your private repo.

Note:- Please replace your private repo URL from `https+auth_token` to `SSH`.
Eg: `git remote add ssh://git@github.com/your_group/your_project.git`

Comment: Thanks @Sam-Sundar for looking into this issue, I tried the suggested approach but the action that you've pointed me out to needs to be configured somehow. I've created a ssh key and I've added it to "deploy keys". hover when running webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.5.3, I am receiving this comment: "key 'ssh-rsa...' does not match GitHub URL pattern. Not treating it as a GitHub deploy key" followed by an error when trying to set up the remote "fatal: 'ssh@github.com/stoicad/umg-interview-private.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository."

Comment: You shouldn't create a deploy key, instead have a jump server with SSH configured and add those keys under a bot account in GitHub. Check if you are able to clone the repo in that jump server and once it's able to clone, add the private key of the jump server to GitHub secret and refer that secret in the action.